# Problema com sistema multimonitor no Linux - Definir Tela Principal

Tags: linux, mint

Meu sistema possui dois monitores de modo que o principal fica no "meio"(ou direita) e o secundário a esquerda.

O problema é que ao que parece o Linux sempre pega o da esquerda para ser o principal. A barra de tarefas e o menu ficam nele e as janelas também abrem nele, inclusive a tela de login.

Há alguma forma de colocar o do meio/direita para ser o principal, pois quando não tenho necessidade de usar os dois mantenho o da esquerda desligado.

Estou usando os drivers proprietários da ATI no Linux Mint 17.

Comment: altera as configurações do monitor, se não resolver, inverte os cabos.

Comment: Um monitor é HDMI e o outro é VGA. O VGA só tem entrada VGA.

Comment: eu não sei se o mint salva as informação do monitor, mas da para alterar, o problema é que o linux costuma dar prioridade ao vga.

Comment: tenta alterar isso direto nos arquivos da interface ou do X11, tenta mudar a prioridade.

Comment: já alterei manualmente usando o xrandr, mas na hora de iniciar o pc, a tela de login fica no monitor a esquerda.

Comment: procura os arquivos de configuração na pasta /etc/ e define o segundo como primario

Comment: Acrescentei esta linha ao final da sessão do monitor.

Option      "Primary" "true"

Comment: se não funcionar, coloque o comando q você usa com o xrand no .xinitrc, ai ele chama o comando quando iniciar a interface

Comment: Obrigado pelos comentários. Depois de alguns dias fuçando, consegui. Parece um problema trivial, mas não é. Principalmente para iniciantes.
Vou escrever uma resposta aqui para minha pergunta.
Obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A primeira vista pode parecer um problema trivial, no entanto sempre que alterava o leiaute dos monitores pelo Catalyst o monitor a esquerda era setado como primário. Ficando nele a tela de login e a barra de tarefas.

Ao que parece o Mint também sempre pega o monitor mais a esquerda como primário.

Depois de muito pesquisar problemas semelhantes, neste link o comando

```
xrandr --output CRT1 --primary --auto --pos 0x0 --output LVDS --auto --left-of CRT1
```

> http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1382165

Porém sempre que reiniciava o sistema ou ajustava a resolução, voltava ficar tudo no monitor mais a esquerda.

Editei o arquivo /etc/X11/xorg.conf e deixei da seguinte maneira como neste neste link

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "amdcccle-Device[1]-0"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    Option      "Monitor-LVDS" "0-LVDS"
    Option      "Monitor-CRT1" "0-CRT1"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection
```

> http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1476796

Mas não resolveu.

Apenas com a dica neste link foi que consegui solucionar o problema.

> http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1468925&page=2&p=11346991#post11346991

Editei o arquivo /etc/X11/xorg.conf inseri o seguinte

```
Section "Monitor"
...
    Option "Primary" "true"
EndSection
```